# Getting table names from the server

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def GetTbname(Id):
    query = "select DatabaseName,TableName from hub.analytics_table where id=%s" % (Id)
    df_table=sql.read_sql(query,Conn_test)
    n_table = len(df_table)
    i=0
    Tbname=''
    while i < n_table :
        Tbname = Tbname + df_table.DatabaseName[i] + '.' +     df_table.TableName[i]
        i = i+1
    return Tbname


tablename1 = GetTbname(1)
tablename2 = GetTbname(2)
tablename3 = GetTbname(3)
print(tablename1)
print(tablename2)
print(tablename3)
```

I need to get the table names from the server into Python. The above codes are all correct but the thing is when i add any new table in the server, I have to manually enter tablename4 = GetTbname(4) and so on ...

Is there any possible solution where instead of entering manually every time my code will be such tat if I type tablename = GetTbname where i will get the entire table.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution is store table names in list liked

```
Tbname=[]
while i < n_table :
    Tb = df_table.DatabaseName[i] + '.' + df_table.TableName[i]
    Tbname.append(Tb)    
    i = i+1
return Tbname
```

Now you can get list of table name and can use as you want.
Try it once

Comment: When I print(tablename) it shows <function GetTbname at 0x7fb0f4e14048> instead of table names bro